# AngularJS select first letter of a set

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I have a list of things that are selectable and a filter area where a user can click the first letter: A B C D, etc

If a user clicks A, I want the URL to be `/products/a` and then I want to filter all products starting with the letter `a`. I'm not entirely sure how to do this.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.startsWithFilter = function(artist) {

    var startMatch = new RegExp($scope.filterLetter, "i");
    return artist.name.substring(0, 1).match(startMatch);
}
```